# First order condition of HP Filter

Tags: econometrics, filter, macroeconomics

The HP Filters for growth and cyclical components is written as:
$$\min_{g_t}\sum_t \left[(y_t-g_t)^2+\lambda\left[(g_{t+1}-g_t)-(g_t-g_{t-1})\right]^2\right].$$

Hodrick and Prescott, on their [paper](https://www0.gsb.columbia.edu/faculty/rhodrick/prescott-hodrick1997.pdf) said that

> If the cyclical components and the second difference of the growth
>   components were identically and independently distributed normal
>   variables with means zero and variances $\sigma_1^2$ and $\sigma_2^2$,
>   the conditional expectation of the $g_t$ given the observations would be
>   the solution to the minimization problem, if
>   $\lambda=\frac{\sigma_1^2}{\sigma_2^2}.$

To prove this statement, what I have known so far is that we need to use Lagrange first-order condition. But, I don't know to which variable I need to differentiate the function. Are they only $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial y_t}=0, \frac{\partial L}{\partial g_{t+1}}=0, \frac{\partial L}{\partial g_t}=0\ \mathbb{and}\ \frac{\partial L}{\partial g_{t-1}}=0?$$ or $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial y_t}=0, \frac{\partial L}{\partial g_t}=0,\ \mathbb{and}\ \frac{\partial L}{\partial \Delta^2g_t}=0?$$ or else?